# Error when insert c# code in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <% string id = Session["user"].ToString(); %>//insert c# code                                                                                                  
    <asp:MenuItem Navigateurl="<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}",id) %>" Text="Lecturer Profile"/>
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </form>
</body>
```

But it has an error: **"Cannot resolve symbol id"**

I'm not sure that I've done the right syntax for inserting c# code in aspx page.

Help!!! I want to Navigate to LecturerProfile.aspx page in front code. Can you give me some advice for a better way to get Session["user"] in aspx page???

Comment: The error is about ID field, because there is no such variable. maybe it should be user.ID?

Comment: Try user instead of Id.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov : oh, sorry, I've updated my question, it's just my mistake when I copied and pasted

Comment: <% ... %> is used to include server-side code in the page's Render method.  It can't be used to set properties of server controls.  Consider using databinding.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

With null check, you can change your markup to this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl='<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}",Session["user"]== null? "0" : Session["user"].ToString()) %>' Text="Lecturer Profile" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
</form>
```

It should be :

```
    <asp:MenuItem Navigateurl='<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}",id) %>' Text="Lecturer Profile"/>
```

Notice the double quote replaced by single quote and removed extra `</asp:MenuItem>`.

But `MenuItem` needs a menu to exist. So your markup should be like this:

```
<% string id = Session["user"].ToString(); %>
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl='<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}",id) %>' Text="Lecturer Profile" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: it still has that error: "cannot resolve symbol id". I wonder if I've inserted c# code by the wrong way

Comment: You need to save something in the session. See my edit.

Comment: @ Vy Clarks- see my last edit. You can use inline null checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's always better to check null validation in sessions

```
<% if (Session["user"] != null)
   {
       string id = Session["user"].ToString();
   }
%>

<asp:MenuItem Navigateurl='<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}",id) %>' Text="Lecturer Profile"/>
```